# Rename multiple columns given character vectors of column names and replacement

Tags: r, dplyr

While this is easy to do with base R or `setnames` `in data.table` or `rename_` in `dplyr` 0.5. Since `rename_` is deprecated, I couldn't find an easy way to do this in `dplyr` 0.6.0.

Below is an example. I want to replace column name in `col.from` with corresponding values in `col.to`:

```
col.from <- c("wt", "hp", "vs")
col.to <- c("foo", "bar", "baz")

df <- mtcars
head(df, 2)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Expected output:

```
names(df)[match(col.from, names(df))] <- col.to
head(df, 2)
#>               mpg cyl disp bar drat   foo  qsec baz am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46   0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02   0  1    4    4
```

How can I do this with `rename` or `rename_at` in `dplyr` 0.6.0?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way to approach it, but

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename_at(vars(col.from), function(x) col.to) %>% head(2)
#               mpg cyl disp bar drat   foo  qsec baz am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46   0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02   0  1    4    4
```

Also note that I live in the future:

```
# packageVersion("dplyr")
# # [1] ‘0.7.0’
```

Comment: Or slightly shorter `df %>% rename_at(vars(col.from), ~col.to)`

Comment: Wow, both are very simple in syntax. The only thing is that it is hard for me to unstand the `rename_at`'s behavior under such case. I thought the `.funs` would be applied to each colname in `.vars`. I didn't expect it will match by position.

Comment: @mt1022 Yep, the one from @docendodiscimus would make a good example in the `?select_all` doc. The function is applied to all selected column names. That means, `function(x)` basically receives the `col.from` values in `x`, then it can do stuff with it - which is in our case just returning a different character vector of length 3.

Comment: `rename_at()` is now superseded with `rename_with()`. The following works: `df %>% rename_with(~col.to, .cols = all_of(col.from))`