# Dplyr rename unquoting

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to rename a variable in a dataframe but can't get the unquoting part to work. I have read http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html and looking at different examples but unfortunately just can't figure it out somehow. This is what I'm currently using, I want to rename the column "x" to "x2" (both are variables):

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,4))
variable_to_rename = "x"
new_variable_name = "x2"
df %>%
  rename_vars(names(.), !! variable_to_rename = !! new_variable_name)
```

The desired output is the dataframe:

```
data.frame(x2 = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,4))
```

As I just commented:
I found the following working code:

```
df %>%
  rename(!!new_variable_name := !!rlang::sym(variable_to_rename))
```

Comment: Sorry, found the answer already: 
df %>%
  rename(!!new_variable_name := !!rlang::sym(variable_to_rename))

Comment: see also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452676/3926543 and the first comment. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe just use names ? `names(df)[1] <- "x2"`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach to rename a single column is as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45729558/4836511). But if you want to use the `dplyr::rename()`, then look at the below answer.

---

Usage of `rename()` function as below would do the needful.

```
df <- rename(df, x2 = x)
df
#  x2 y
#1  1 2
#2  2 3
#3  3 4
```