# rename column names dynamically in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

Here's an example

```
temp <- mtcars
colnames(temp)[grepl("ge", colnames(temp))] <- "garbage"
```

Output

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am garbage carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1       4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1       4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1       4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0       3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0       3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0       3    1
```

I only know what the column name will start with ("ge") but I'm not sure of the column name exactly

I want a solution that works in a `dplyr` chain

```
temp %>%
   rename(vars(starts_with("ge")), "garbage")
Error: All arguments must be named
```

of course doesn't work. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rename_at`. If you know that only one column starts with "ge", this will work:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("ge")), funs(paste0("garbage")))
```

If you want to rename more than one column, the function in `funs()` needs to return a vector of names, or do something like `gsub()` to add something to the existing column names.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Didn't realize it existed (in addition to the other `verb_at`s.) And how you got it accept an argument doesn't make a lot of sense but that's probably how it was designed.

Comment: I find the syntax for the `_all`, `_if` and `_at` variants quite confusing myself. There must be a good tutorial somewhere!

Comment: Nice answer, but it's a bit odd that you have to provide a function to specify a replacement character string.

Comment: I'm sure there's a cleaner, cleverer way. I tried it, it worked :)

Comment: For renaming single column, an alternatively solution is `mtcars %>% rename_at(vars(starts_with("ge")), ~"garbage")`. For why this works, see comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452676/3926543.

Comment: @mt1022 - I'm on an older version of dplyr at the moment - does that expand to multiple columns if I put a vector in place of `"garbage"` ?

Comment: @thelatemail, something like `mtcars %>% rename_at(vars(starts_with("d")), ~c("d1", "d2"))`? Sure, this also works. I would prefer `mtcars %>% rename_at(vars(starts_with("d")), ~rep("grabage", length(.)))`

Comment: Thanks @mt1022 for the link as well

Comment: What is `vars` in this context? I can't see where this comes from?

Comment: @MichaelBarton `vars()` is a `dplyr` function (see `?vars`). It is not so well documented.