# Changing Column Names using a Key

Tags: r, rename, purrr

I have a data frame with 3 letter key column headings, which looks like:

```
MFB   MBB   WBB
 X     X     X
```

and another data frame with the full names:

```
Key   Descr
MFB   Men's Football
MBB   Men's Basketball
WBB   Women's Basketball
```

My question is, how would I go about renaming the columns so the original table looks like:

```
Men's Football   Men's Basketball   Women's Basketball
       X                X                   X
```

There are about 80 column headings I want to rename, so manually renaming each column is not desired.  My guess is it could be done using a for loop or the 'map2' function from the 'purrr' library, but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Rename multiple columns given character vectors of column names and replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452108/rename-multiple-columns-given-character-vectors-of-column-names-and-replacement)

To make your question fully reproducible, let's start with

```
library(tidyverse)
sports <- tibble(MFB=c("bears", "texans", "packers"), 
    MBB=c("bulls", "heat", "bucks"), 
    WBB=c("dream", "sky", "sun"))

pairs <- tibble(Key=c("MFB", "MBB", "WBB"), 
    Descr=c("Men's Football", "Men's Basketball", "Women's Basketball"))
```

If the keys can be sorted in the same order as the original column headings, then a simple

`setNames(sports,pairs$Descr)`

works. Otherwise

`sports %>% rename_at(pairs$Key, ~pairs$Descr)`